# How to find the dual problem of this LP?

Tags: linear-programming, duality-theorems

I want to find the dual problem of the following LP:

$\min c'x$ s.t. $Ax=b,x\ge a$ where a>0.

I'm considering substitute $y=x-a$ so that it becomes:

$\min c'y+c'a$ s.t. $Ax=b-Aa,y\ge 0$.

I know I can drop the constant $c'a$ and then write the dual problem. I'm wondering is there a way to write the dual of it without dropping the constant? Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are two other approaches. The first one is using the Lagrangian. The second is by writing the problem as:
\begin{align}
\min \quad & c^Tx \\
\text{s.t.} \quad & \begin{pmatrix}A \\ -A \\ I\end{pmatrix}x \geq \begin{pmatrix}b \\ -b \\ a\end{pmatrix} \\
& x \geq 0.
\end{align}
The dual is:
\begin{align}
\max \quad & \begin{pmatrix}b \\ -b \\ a\end{pmatrix}^Ty \\
\text{s.t.} \quad & \begin{pmatrix}A \\ -A \\ I\end{pmatrix}^T y \leq  c \\
& y \geq 0.
\end{align}
You could simplify this to:
\begin{align}
\max \quad & b^Ty_1 + a^T y_2 \\
\text{s.t.} \quad & A^Ty_1 + y_2 \leq  c \\
& y_2 \geq 0.
\end{align}